# Fastest way to draw [grayscale bitmap * colorValue] additively to screen on Android

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, bitmap, alphablending

What I want to do is multiple a grayscale alpha bitmap with an RGB color value, and then draw the resulting RGB bitmap to screen additively, that is, at each pixel I want:

```
p_new[r/g/b] = p_old[r/g/b] + colorValue[r/g/b] * grayscaleBitmapValue
```

I know I can construct an intermediate RGB bitmap or texture holding (colorValue[r/g/b] * grayscaleBitmapValue), but I'd rather avoid this wasteful step if possible, because each alpha bitmap will be multiplied with quite a number of different color values.

What's the fastest way to do this in either 2D or OpenGL ES ?

Answer (score 1):

For 2D drawing, set up your Paint object like this:

```
paint.setColorFilter(
    new PorterDuffColorFilter(colorValue, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD));
```

For OpenGL, your fragment shader could look like this:

```
varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec4 multColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texcoord)*multColor;
}
```

... and call glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE) to do additive blending.

Comment: I'll test this. Are support all transfer modes and filters required for Android device/hardware ? Are they hardware-accelerated or am I better off (for performance) implementing it myself (I already have the C/C++ code) ?

Comment: Drawing with the Paint object won't be hardware accelerated, but it'll work on all devices. It'll be about as fast, if not faster, than your own C/C++ code.